# How can I compute the null vector using QR factorization?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, matrix-decomposition

Assume that you have a matrix $X$ and you want to compute the complex eigenvectors. You only know the complex eigenvalues.

With that information, you could solve the null space formula $$(A-\lambda I)v = 0$$

With this MATLAB code

```
% Create a matrix 
A = [2 3 1;
     4 1 -3;
     2 0 4];

% Compute the eigenvalues
[~, eigenvalues] = eig(A, 'vector')

% Iterate the eigenvalues to compute the eigenvectors
eigenvectors = [];
for i = 1:length(eigenvalues)
   eigenvalue = eigenvalues(i)
   V = null(A - eigenvalue * eye(size(A))); % (A - λ*I)v = 0
   eigenvectors = [eigenvectors V];
end
```

We print the eigenvectors

```
 0.5718 +      0i  -0.4879 -      0i  -0.4879 -      0i
-0.8014 +      0i  -0.3148 - 0.3824i  -0.3148 + 0.3824i
-0.1756 +      0i  -0.4002 + 0.5971i  -0.4002 - 0.5971i
```

We can always to a check if `(A - λ*I)v` is actully zero

```
% (A - λ*I)v = 0
(A - eigenvalues(1) * eye(size(A)))*eigenvectors(:, 1)

% Output:
-2.4147e-15
1.0270e-15
5.7825e-16
```

This eigenvector corresponds to the eigenvalue `-2.5116` and MATLAB's `D = eig(X)` function give the same result.

```
 0.5718
-0.8014
-0.1756
```

The rest of the eigenvectors in MATLAB gives`[V, ~] = eig(X)` gives.

```
   0.5718 +      0i  -0.2716 - 0.4053i  -0.2716 + 0.4053i
  -0.8014 +      0i   0.1424 - 0.4744i   0.1424 + 0.4744i
  -0.1756 +      0i  -0.7188 +      0i  -0.7188 -      0i
```

**Question:**

Notice that I'm using `null` command to solve for the null vector. Is it possible for me to use QR factorization instead of `null` to solve the null vector? If yes, how?

Comment: See the answer to [this question].  Obviously to find the null space of $A$ you would QR-factorize $A^T$.
 (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356327/full-qr-decomposition-orthonormal-basis-for-the-null-space-of-at)